# python pass request args to function

Tags: python

I have a function

```
def doStuff():
    thing = str(request.args.get('thing'))
    return thing
```

I want to call it from a script with an argument `'foo'`.  How can I do this?

Comment: you would have to have the function take an argument ex. `def doStuff(arg):`

Comment: so just def mything = doStuff('foo') and change doStuff() to doStuff(arg)?

Comment: Yes but then you should use the arg in the function answer posted of proper usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def doStuff(bar):
    thing = str(bar)
    return thing

doStuff('foo')
```